# How to use websockets to send message to specific user with Flask?

Tags: python, websocket, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

In a website I'm building with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), people can send each other PMs. When a user receives a pm, I now want to implement a notification similar to how StackOverflow does it. Since SO implements this using websockets, I got myself started in websockets using [this tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) about implementing [Flask-socketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (which works with [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)).

I downloaded [the example](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example) as made by the tutorial, and I understand the code within it. What I do not understand however, is:

1. How can I know whether a logged in person has the website open and is connected to websockets?
2. How can I send a message to that specific user?

So let's say that I have a simple route in which people can POST a PM to another user:

```
@app.route('/admin/pm', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def pms():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        savePM(g.user.id, request.form['toUserId'], request.form['text'])
        # How do I emit a message here to the user to whom this message is sent?
    return render_template('sendPM.html')
```

My comment already says it: how do I emit a message to the user to whom this message was sent from there? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Following the tips from Miguel I thought of creating a room with the name being the `user.id`, so I now created the following connect and disconnect events:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
@login_required
def websocketConnect():
    join_room(g.user.id)
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'}, room=g.user.id)

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
@login_required
def websocketDisconnect():
    leave_room(g.user.id)
    print('Client disconnected')
```

But upon connecting I get the stacktrace below. Isn't the `g` object created with socketio routes?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/socketio/virtsocket.py", line 403, in _receiver_loop
    retval = pkt_ns.process_packet(pkt)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 164, in process_packet
    return self.call_method_with_acl('recv_connect', packet)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 240, in call_method_with_acl
    return self.call_method(method_name, packet, *args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 282, in call_method
    return method(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 79, in recv_connect
    self.socketio._dispatch_message(app, self, 'connect')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 137, in _dispatch_message
    ret = self.messages[namespace.ns_name][message](*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 758, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kramer65/repos/vg/app/views/webviews.py", line 418, in websocketConnect
    join_room(g.user.id)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I know whether a logged in person has the website open and is connected to websockets?

It is up to you to keep track of this. When a user connects to the socket endpoint you will get the `connect` event, and right there you can register the user as connected. The connect event handler has access to the `session`, so if logged in users have their id or nickname written to the session you can access that in the socket connect handler.

Also, when the user leaves you will get a `disconnect` event.

> How can I send a message to that specific user?

The easiest way to identify users is to put them in rooms, then you can emit messages to those rooms. If you need to address users individually, then just put each user in a different room, named after the user's nickname or id. The perfect place to manage user rooms is, once again, the `connect` and `disconnect` event handlers.

Not exactly what you want, but I have written a slightly more complex example that uses rooms:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat

Comment: Awesome, a message from the master of tutorials himself! :) Thanks for your explanation. Good to hear that I can keep track myself using the connect event, that makes it more flexible. Just a question about the rooms though. Is creating a room "cheap"? As in, if I have thousands of users, is it okay to create a room for every person?

Comment: As you can see in the edit in my initial question, I now wrote a simple `connect` event, but the g.object doesn't seem to be available in a socketio route. Would you know how I would be able to create a room for the user if I can't know which logged in user is the user that tries to connect?

Comment: That's correct, `g` is available, but the `before_request` handlers do not run for socket events, so the code that populates `g` does not get a chance to run, as documented. You have to write the user's name or id to the session (maybe when the user logs in), as the session is recreated in the socket event handlers.